# How do you change the Power BI data-source version?

Tags: powerbi, tabular

I am wanting to use ALM Toolkit to compare Power BI datasets across different environments. When I connect to Power BI it states that "datasets have default data-source versions of PowerBI_V1, which is not supported for comparison..."

What is the affect of changing the data-source version? Is this possible through the front end (rather than this app).

I cannot find any documentation on it other than the API library which doesn't give much info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.tabular.powerbidatasourceversion?view=analysisservices-dotnet

Thanks